# What does it mean that "a declaration shadows a parameter"?

Tags: c++, function, integer

I am trying to make a function that returns double the integer number that I will pass to it.  I am getting the following error message with my code:

> declaration of 'int x' shadows a parameter int x; "

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
int doublenumber();
using namespace std;
int doublenumber(int x)// <-- this is the function which returns double the value .
{
    int x;
    return 2 * x;
    cout << endl;
}
int main()
{
    int a;
    cout << "Enter the number that you want to double it : " << endl;
    cin >> a;
    doublenumber(a);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are naming a local variable the same as a parameter. Delete the first line in `doublenumber`. Also, the last line of that func never executes as it is after the `return`.

Comment: Please make the effort of providing an error-free and meaningful title.

Comment: guys after i edited my code it goes right but the it never return the double value and i don't know why ? , any suggestions !?

Comment: You never do anything with it. Try `int n = doublenumber(a); cout << n << endl;`

Comment: @JohnnyMopp thank you so much man now it works right thanks for all of you guys .

Comment: I vote to reopen the question, since it is the best duplicate I found asking for the meaning of this error message.

Answer (score 47):

You have `x` as a parameter and then try to declare it also as a local variable, which is what the complaint about "shadowing" refers to.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int doublenumber(int x)
{
return 2*x;
}
int main()
{
int a;
cout << "Enter the number that you want to double it : " << endl;
cin>>a;
int d = doublenumber(a);

cout << "Double : " << d << endl;

return 0;
}
```

There are some problem with your code. Your declaration and definition of function dies not match. So remove declaration as no necessity of it.

You are declaring local x variable inside function which will shadow your function arguments.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: @swapnil thank you so much but your code doesn't work with me , there is something missing :)

Comment: @grandx I got your point... Remove line int doublenumber(); as your definition and declaration of function does not match. Even no need of function declaration as we are providing the definition before main.

Answer (score 2):

I did it because your advice was so helpful, and this is the final result :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int doublenumber(int x)
{
    return 2*x;
}

int main()
{
    int a;
    cout << "Enter the number that you want to double it : " << endl;
    cin>>a;
    int n= doublenumber(a);
    cout << "the double value is : " << n << endl;
    return 0;
}
```