# Segmentation Fault when dealing with 2D Arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic, segmentation-fault

I'm am trying to dynamically make 2d arrays that are then supposed to be iterated through to check their contents. Whenever I try to use a function that indexes the array I get a segmentation fault. The two functions that are creating the problems are the printg() and get() functions. I'm not sure exactly what I'm doing wrong, but neither of them will work properly for me.

Any help would be great. Thank you.

```
#ifndef _GRID_H
#define _GRID_H

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Grid
{
    public:
        Grid();
        Grid(const Grid& g2);
        Grid(int x, int y, double density);
        Grid(string file);
        ~Grid();

        bool check(int x, int y); //check  if a cell is inhabited or not
        bool isEmpty();//check if a grid is living
        bool equals(const Grid& g2);//checks if two grids are equal
        void kill(int x, int y);//kill a cell
        void grow(int x, int y);//grow a cell
        int getSize();
        int getNumRows();
        int getNumCol();
        int getNumLiving();
        void printg(int r, int c);
        char get(int x, int y) const;

    private:
        int size; //number of cells in grid
        int row; //row length (number of columns)
        int column; //column length (number of rows)
        int num_living; //number of X's in the grid

        char** myGrid;

};

#endif


#include "Grid.h"

#ifndef _GRID_C
#define _GRID_C

#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>

//compile with g++ -I /home/cpsc350/GameOfLife Grid.cpp

using namespace std;

Grid::Grid() //do i need a default constructor????
{
    char myGrid[10][10] = {{0,1,2,3}, {4,5,6,7}, {8,9,10,11}};
    row = 10;
    column = 10;
    size = 100;
}

Grid::Grid(const Grid& g2)//copy constructor/////////////help
{
    size = g2.size;
    row = g2.row;
    column = g2.column;
    num_living = g2.num_living;

    char** myGrid = new char*[row];
    for(int i = 0; i < row; i++)
        myGrid[i] = new char[column];

    for(int i1 = 0; i1 < row; i1++)
    {
        for(int i2 = 0; i2 < column; i2++)
        {
            //copy(&g2[i1][i2], &g2[i1][i2]+row*column,&myGrid[i1][i2]);
            myGrid[i1][i2] = g2.get(i1,i2);
        }
    }
}

Grid::Grid(int x, int y, double density)
{

    char** myGrid = new char*[x];
    for(int i = 0; i < x; i++)
        myGrid[i] = new char[y];

    row = x;
    column = y;
    size = x*y;
    num_living = size * density;
    string str = "";

    for(int a = 0; a < num_living; a++)//adds the density of X's to a string
    {
        str += 'X';
    }

    for(int a = 0; a < size - num_living; a++)//adds the rest to the string
    {
        str += '-';
    }
    int randnum;
    //randomly generates indicies in the string str and puts them into the array
    for(int i1 = 0; i1 < column; i1++)
    {
        for(int i2 = 0; i2 < row; i2++)
        {
            //generate random numbers from index 0 to length of string - 1
            if(str.length()>1)
            {
                randnum = (rand()%(str.length()-1))+1;
            }
            else
            {
                randnum = 0;
            }
            myGrid[i1][i2] = str[randnum];
            str.erase(randnum);
        }
    }
}

Grid::Grid(string file)
{
    num_living = 0;
    //code to create a 2d array from a filepath
    ifstream openfile(file);

    //error handling
    if(! openfile)
    {
        cout << "Error, file could not be opened" << endl;
        exit(0);
    }

    openfile >> column;//gets number of rows
    openfile >> row;//gets number of columns
    size = row*column;

    char** myGrid = new char*[row];
    for(int i = 0; i < row; i++)
        myGrid[i] = new char[column];

    for(int x = 0; x<column; x++)
    {
        for(int y = 0; y<row; y++)
        {
            openfile >> myGrid[x][y];

            if(! openfile)//error handling
            {
                cout << "Error reading file at " << row << "," << column << endl;
            }

            if(myGrid[x][y] == 'X')
            {
                num_living++;
            }
        }
    }

    openfile.close();
}

Grid::~Grid()
{
    if(myGrid)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < row; i++)
        {
            delete []myGrid[i];
        }
        delete []myGrid;
    }
}

void Grid::kill(int x, int y)
{
    if(myGrid[x][y] == 'X')
    {
        num_living--;
    }
    myGrid[x][y] = '-';
}

void Grid::grow(int x, int y)
{
    if(myGrid[x][y] == '-')
    {
        num_living++;
    }
    myGrid[x][y] = 'X';
}

bool Grid::check(int x, int y)
{
    if(y<0 || x<0)
    {
        return(false);
    }
    return (myGrid[x][y] == 'X');
}

bool Grid::isEmpty()
{
    return (num_living == 0);
}

bool Grid::equals(const Grid& g2)
{
    if(size != g2.size) //checks if sizes are equal
    {
        return false;
    }
    if(row != g2.row)//checks if numRows are equal
    {
        return false;
    }
    if(column != g2.column)//checks if numCol are equal
    {
        return false;
    }
    if(num_living != g2.num_living)//checks if numliving are equal
    {
        return false;
    }
    for(int x = 0; x < row; x++)//checks each element
    {
        for(int y = 0; y < column; y++)
        {
            if(myGrid[x][y] != g2.get(x,y))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

int Grid::getSize()
{
    return(size);
}

int Grid::getNumRows()
{
    return(column);
}

int Grid::getNumCol()
{
    return(row);
}

int Grid::getNumLiving()
{
    return(num_living);
}

void Grid::printg(int r, int c)
{
    for(int x = 0; x < r; x++)
    {
        for(int y = 0; y < c; y++)
        {
            cout << myGrid[x][y];
        }
    cout << endl;
    }
}

char Grid::get(int x, int y) const
{
    return myGrid[x][y];
}

#endif
```

Comment: `char myGrid[10][10]` is not `this->myGrid`. I didnt read all the code, but suspect you never make `this->myGrid` point anywhere

Comment: didnt find a good dupe, maybe this is close enough: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32311372/what-does-it-mean-that-a-declaration-shadows-a-parameter

Comment: Your code violates [The Rule of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three): assignment operator is not overloaded.

Comment: Actual help: run under a debugger, or examine your core file with one. Segmentation faults are _full_ of information, including the complete program state at the time they happen. If that doesn't get you anywhere, look for non-local memory damage with valgrind or asan. If you need further help, you'll need to work on reducing your code to the [minimal complete verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: `#define _GRID_H` That identifier is reserved. By defining it, your program will have undefined behaviour. You should use another header guard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem that I see at first is that both your default and copy constructor do not initialize myGrid. what you are doing in them will create an additional array with the same name which 'shadows' myGrid. instead you have to do:

```
Grid::Grid(const Grid& g2)
{
    size = g2.size;
    row = g2.row;
    column = g2.column;
    num_living = g2.num_living;

    myGrid = new char*[row]; // removed "char**" at the start of this line
    for(int i = 0; i < row; i++)
        myGrid[i] = new char[column];

    for(int i1 = 0; i1 < row; i1++)
    {
        for(int i2 = 0; i2 < column; i2++)
        {
            //copy(&g2[i1][i2], &g2[i1][i2]+row*column,&myGrid[i1][i2]);
            myGrid[i1][i2] = g2.get(i1,i2);
        }
    }
}
```

your default constructor has the same problem. but note that you can't initialize it with braces. but you don't have to have a default constructor if you are not using it.