# Declaration of 'int a' shadows a parameter

Tags: c++

I am new to c++ and trying to calculate `Xk+1 = Xk - a*Xk*h` for user entered values. Here's what I tried:

```
#include<stdio.h>

float fn_calculate(int x1, int x0, int a, float h)
{
    int x;
    int a;
    float h;
    int k;
    for(k=-1; k<=100; k++);
    {
     float x1=x0-a*x0*h;

     printf("please enter a 'x' value:\n");
     scanf("%f",&x);
     printf("please enter a 'a' value:\n");
     scanf("%f",&a);
     printf("please enter a 'h' value:\n");
     scanf("%f",&h);
     printf("the result is: %f\n", x1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Pick a different name...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does it mean that "a declaration shadows a parameter"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32311372/what-does-it-mean-that-a-declaration-shadows-a-parameter)

Comment: In `float fn_calculate(int x1, int x0, int a, float h)` why are you attempting to ask for the values of  `a` and `h` if these are passed by value from the calling function? Also why do you declare local variables of the same names `a` and `h` inside the function? And what is the use of the `x1` parameter that you also shadow? Maybe your function needed only 1 parameter?

Comment: Also do you really want the user to type 3 numbers 102 times?

Comment: This is calculated the first time before `a` and `h` have values: `float x1=x0-a*x0*h;` the second and subsequent times its calculated with the previous values.

Comment: My advice is to start with the basics before trying to write the code for this. You seem to be coding by guessing and that does not work with `c++`.

Comment: thank you for all your comments

Comment: I really wonder at what level we should start to reject questions: To me it's so much obvious what the problem is, and I thing anyone able to write successful programs should see it, too.

Answer (score 3):

You declare `a` inside the function. There's a parameter with the same name, `a`.

Doing that you cannot access the parameter `a` but only the local variable defined. You should change the name of either.

The same happens for `h`. You have to choose different names for both of them.

Answer (score 0):

The right expression with main function is here:

```cpp
#include<stdio.h>

float fn_calculate() {
    float x0;
    int k;
    float h, a;
    for (k = -1; k <= 100; k++);
    {
        printf("please enter a 'x' value:\n");
        scanf("%f", &x0);
        printf("please enter a 'a' value:\n");
        scanf("%f", &a);
        printf("please enter a 'h' value:\n");
        scanf("%f", &h);
        float x1 = x0 - a * x0 * h;
        printf("the result is: %f\n", x1);
    }
    return 0;
}
int main(){
    // you will calculate the formula below. 
    printf("x_{n+1} = x_{n} - a * x_{n} * h ; \n");
    fn_calculate();
    return 0;
}
```

---

By the way, **note these problems below** may be good for you:

1. Add some comments;
2. Add a `main` function for your program;
3. Learn about the parameter passing;
4. Learn about variable type, like `%d` for int and `%f` for float.